# How to include a script for use anywhere in the Add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my firefox addon, I have a script called "global.js" that I need to use in several dialogues (xul).  Do I need to include the script in each xul file, or is there a better way?  I call the same function from each dialogue, and so I need them available to any place in the addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to include it in each XUL file. If you have multiple files that you need to access you could reference them using [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules) from the `global.js` file so you don't have to keep changing multiple XUL files whenever you add a new dependency.

There are other options (like having a single XUL file and a bunch of overlays to modify it for specific purposes) but without knowing anything more about your use case, I'd say you're probably better off just biting the bullet and including that one script file everywhere.

Comment: Including the script in each xul file is what I am doing now.  I thought of using modules, but I need to be able to share the values of the variables.  In my study, I seem to remember something about not being able to do that.  Am I right about that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "share the value of the variables", but you can export symbols from modules. You can just have to specify explicitly which symbols to export.

Comment: What I mean is, that if I set a variable in one of my js files, or set a variable inside a module, I want to access that variable from either my module or my js files.  In other words, if I set a = "bob";, then I need to get the value of a from either the script or the module.

Comment: For what it's worth, that doesn't sound like very good coding practice to me. Better to keep things encapsulated and pass the values you need into and out of the module explicitly. That's how I'd do it anyway.